# svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, svn-ssh

Previous i was using ubuntu 12.04 for my project purposes. when i were using 12.04 i used to checkout source via Openssh server an i was able check out source.

Now i migrated to Ubuntu 16.04.Now i am trying to check out from the same svn via openssh it is not happening i getting following error

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://XXXXX@YYYY.ZZZ.com/repos/'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

then i tried debugging i got the following log

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to svnsm.ami.com [172.16.96.74] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_3.8.1p1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_3.8.1p1 pat OpenSSH_3.* compat 0x01000000
debug1: Authenticating to svnsm.ami.com:22 as 'chinnainah'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:dZPbSQEmL+bIU8lsK0c3M00FHYTXdeu+Ki3w1Q6mnsg
debug1: Host 'svnsm.ami.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/chinniah/keys/chinniah.pri - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://chinnainah@svnsm.ami.com/svnrepos/granada'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

could any one please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had this exact same issue after upgrading 14.04 to 16.04.

Found the solution here: http://www.joho.se/2016/05/13/ssh-keys-are-no-longer-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts-help/

The error is here:

```
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/chinniah/keys/chinniah.pri - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
```

The temp fix is adding this line to your home/yourusername/.ssh/config file.

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

Now restart ssh:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

The problem is with the ssh key file. OpenSSH 7 doesn't allow ssh-dss keys by default. Here is an article I found describing why: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys

Answer (score 0):

**SVN connection issue**

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://Ip/repo'
svn: E000113: Can't connect to host '

Solution:

Please check your firewall

Add svn port in Firewall & reload

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3690/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as mentioned in the main answer, but it was compounded by the fact that after a number of tries my IP got blocked.
By the time I started adding the -v flags to ssh I didn't get any information.
By using a different connection I was eventually able to login into the server. Then I removed my IP from `/etc/hosts.deny` (or wherever your monitoring software is storing them like `/usr/share/denyhosts/data`).

In my particular case I fixed it by adding a pub/priv key type that ssh accepted by default.